# URL tracking functionality

Tags: javascript, html

I want my webpage to have two parts. The top part has a textbox. When the user types a URL into the textbox, the bottom part browses to the content of that URL. When the user clicks a link within the bottom part, the bottom part navigates to the new URL, and the textbox in the top part changes to the new URL. How can I do it?

NOTE: This behavior is the same as in Google Translate (e.g. [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=de.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA)), but without any translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### first problem..

*Same origin issue*

The only way to achieve what you are asking is exactly the way google translate does what it does - which is to use a server-side powered script as a proxy request:

> http://translate.google.com/translate_un?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA&lang=de&usg=ALkJrhgoLkbUGvOPUCHoNZIkVcMQpXhxZg

The above is the URL taken from the iframe that Google translate uses to display the translated page. The main thing to note is that the domain part of the URL is the same as the parent page's URL `http://translate.google.com` -- if both your frame and your parent window **do not** share the same domain, then your parent window's JavaScript wont be able to access anything within the iframe. It will be blocked by your browser's in-built security.

Obviously the above wont be a problem if in your project you are only ever going to be navigating your own pages *(on the same domain)*, but considering you are proffering Google Translate as an example I'm assuming not.

*What would Google do?*

What the above URL does is to ask the server-side to fetch the wikipedia page and return it so that the iframe can display it - but to the iframe this page appears to be hosted on `translate.google.com` rather than `wikipedia`. This means that the iframe stays within the same origin as the parent window, and means that JavaScript can be used to edit or modify the page within the iframe.

#### next problem....

*Rewrite the proxied content*

Basically what I'm saying is that this can't be achieved with just HTML and client-side JavaScript - you need to have something to help from the server-side i.e. PHP, Python, Ruby, Lisp, Node.. and so on. This script will be responsible for making sure the proxied page appears/renders correctly e.g. you will have to make sure relative links to content/images/css on the original server are not broken *(you can use the `base` tag or physically rewrite relative links)*. There are also many sites that would see this as an illegal use of their site, as per their site's terms of use and so should be black listed from your service.

#### final problem..?

*Prevent the user from breaking away from your proxy*

Once you have your proxy script, you can then use an iframe *(please avoid using old framesets)*, and a bit of JavaScript magic that `onload` or `ondomready` of the iframe rewrites all of the links, forms and buttons in the page. This is so that when clicked or submitted, they post to your proxy script rather than the original destination. This rewrite code would also have to send the original destination to your proxy script some how - like `u` in the Google translate URL. Once you've sorted this, it will mean your iframe will reload with the new destination content, but - all importantly - your iframe will stay on the same domain.

#### too many problems!

*If it were me, personally, I'd rethink your strategy*

Overall this is not a simple task, and it isn't 100% fullproof either because there are many things that will cause problems:

1. Certain sites are designed to break out of frames.
2. There are ways a user can navigate from a page that can not be easily rewritten i.e. any navigation powered by JavaScript.
3. Certain pages are designed to break when served up from the wrong host.
4. Sites that do this kind of 'proxying' of other websites can get into hot water with regards to copyright and usage.

The reason why Google can do it is because they have a lot of time, money and resources... oh and a great deal of what Google translate does is actually handled on the server-side - not in JavaScript.

#### suggestions

If you are looking for tracking users navigating through your own site:

- Use Google Analytics.
- Or implement a simple server-side tracking system using cookies.

If you are looking to track users coming to your site and then travelling on to the rest of the world wide web:

- Give up, web technologies are designed to prevent things like this.
- Or join an online marketing company, they do their best to get around the prevention of things like this.

Comment: @MikaH. no worries :) apologies for the negative answer -- unfortunately I needed to implement something like the above a while ago and it was rather a nightmare *(all because I disovered each problem one after the other)*. In the end, for my solution, I used an Air app powered by Flash using an embedded WebKit browser... but this means the user has to install your app -- it wont run in-browser.

Answer (score 0):

add a javascript function to your second frame -

```
<frame id="dataframe" src="frame_a.htm" onload="load()">
```

let the text box have an id - say "test"

```
function load()
{
document.getElementById('test').value=document.getElementById('dataframe').src
}
```

Comment: But when the user types a URL into the textbox, how does the bottom part browse to the content of that URL?